# Importing representations from Layer File?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, import, layer-file, representation

I'm trying to incorporate representations as part of my data model. I have set up representation rule for my feature class, which is part of a feature dataset.

The way I have the data categorized is by unique value field. There are four categories - A(105 records), B (35 Records), C (54 Records) and D(38 Records). I have also renamed the labels. I've created the representation in ArcMap and I can see this fine in the FGDB.

I'd like to import this representation symbology into a clean copy of the same layer, which resides in a different location. I am using 'Add Representation' tool to achieve this, however the output is not correct.

I have saved the representation FC to a layer file, which acts as the 'Import Rule Layer' in the 'Add Representation' toolbox. However the output's representation FC symbology, although classified to 4 categories from the initial representation, aggregates all values into the first symbol - A, which now contains all 232 records and these are symbolised according to category A. The representation does not see any records in classes B,C or D, however I can see these remaining categories in the representation tab.

I'm not sure why this is occurring.

Comment: Are you still trying to figure this one out?  Are you doing this via modelbuilder, a script, or a manual process?